# Power BI summing a column instead of breaking it out by role

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have three tables: Actuals, Estimates, and a Master Projects list.

If I create a bar chart (clustered, stacked, or 100% stacked) by selecting the Role and Hours for the Actuals OR the Estimates, it works fine.  It shows the hours for the project broken out by role.

But if I select the Role and Hours for the Actuals AND the Estimates, it breaks.

I need a chart that shows, by project (I'm using a slicer to select), the Estimates by role with the corresponding Actuals.  So the PM Estimates should be a bar and right next to it should be the PM Actuals.

But what is happening is I get the PM Estimates for a project and a sum of all (PM, AN, and RN) the Actual hours for that project.

I'm also encountering an issue where I am unable to make a relationship between the Estimates and Actuals.  I have to use a Master Project list to act as the go between.   If I try to make a relationship between the Actuals and Estimates using the Project as the relationship, it says, "You can't create a relationship between these two columns because one of the columns must have unique values."

Here are the examples of my tables and the results:

**Estimates**

[image: Estimates]

**Actuals**

[image: Actuals]

**Master Project List**

[image: Master]

**Relationships - I have to include the master project list...I cannot simply make a relationship between the projects column in the Estimates and Actuals**

[image: Relationships]

**Actuals Chart**

[image: ActualsChart]

**Estimates Chart**

[image: EstimatesChart]

**This is what happens when I attempt to combine the estimates and actuals into a single chart.  It will break the hours out by role for the Estimates but will combine all the hours for all roles for the actuals.**

[image: EstActChart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using one or the other `Role` column for your chart x-axis and the tables don't have a way to cross-filter that column from one table to another.

A couple of possible solutions come to mind. The simpler one would be to create a calculated table

`Roles = VALUES ( Estimates[Role] )`

and set a 1-to-many relationship from that table to `Estimates` and `Actuals` in your model. Then you can use the `Roles[Role]` column on the x-axis and it should filter both tables correctly.

The other approach would be to write a measure that explicitly filters the role. If you are using `Estimate[Role]` on the x-axis then the `Actuals` table is the one that needs filtering and you could write

```
ActualHoursSum =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Actuals[ActualHours] ),
    FILTER ( Actuals, Actual[Role] IN VALUES ( Estimates[Role] ) )
)
```

You may also be able to use the [`TREATAS` function to propagate filters](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/propagate-filters-using-treatas-in-dax/) how you want.

Comment: Fantastic...that really helped. Still new to Power BI and seeing how you did that helps me understand the way Power BI looks at relationships. That actually clears up a lot of other questions I was pondering. Many thanks!